# Detect Windows full disk encryption generically

Tags: windows, encryption, filesystems, disk

I'm looking for a generic way to detect whether or not a disk is encrypted in Windows. I know about tools like EDD, which detect particular encryption software by looking for its signatures, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to create an encryptor-agnostic solution.

For example, a solution my coworker proposed would be to read a known plain text file from within Windows, and then read that same "file" again directly from the disk, based on the physical position of the file according to Windows. If the two chunks of data are different, then the disk is encrypted.

Problem is, I don't know if such file descriptors or access methods even exist within Windows. Does anyone have any ideas or pointers? Alternatives?

Any direction is appreciated!

Comment: Just to help us answer your question, **why** do you want to do this?

Comment: Fair question! We're an IT security company that performs both one-time and continuous audits. We'd like to be able to provide a statistic about what percentage of an organization's portable devices (laptops, notebooks, etc.) have unencrypted hard drives that could present a security risk if the device were taken offsite and stolen from its owner. Right now we do this via a survey, but we'd like to be able to do it automatically.

Comment: One other detail is that we do have administrative access to all the computers in question, so we can run anything on them that we need to.

Comment: Another case to consider: some encryption happens transparently to the OS, which would fail the test that you described above. Examples of that are when a disk implements encryption inside the hardware itself, or when encryption is implemented in software inside the storage virtualization platform (like NetApp, VMware vSAN, GCE, AWS EBS, etc.). Detecting whether those are encrypted would require calls to the APIs of those platforms.